# HTML5 form validation triggering on correct value after setting setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've set a `setCustomValidity()` to every input `type=number` in my form to translate the default error messages.
The messages are now translated and appear when an incorrect number is inserted. The problem is that now, the error messages will always trigger on form submit even if the value is correct.

I don't know if this is a bug in HTML5 but here are the steps to replicate in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruimelodev/hpfabnwp/):

- Inset the value `1234...1234` and click on submit
- A message saying `This is an invalid number` will appear
- Now insert just `1234` and click on submit
- The same message appears even when the value is a valid number

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very good question buddy.

**You need to clear/reset the `setCustomValidity` after setting a value**. But unfortunately Chrome handles `.setCustomValidity` in a odd way. And because the `.setCustomValidity` is handled by the browser the issue is browser dependent. Switch to full JS validation and remove parts that use `.setCustomValidity` to fix the problem.

You can usually clear the `setCustomValidity` by `setCustomValidity('')` setting it to an empty string but it wont because the browser validates on submit which you need to override like how I have shown below

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hpfabnwp/1/)

**How to solve?**

The trick is

> Browsers must invoke the interactive validation BEFORE 'submit' event is fired. You need to reset setCustomValidity() before 'submit' event if you want a browser to show a validation message again.

```
$('[type=number]').on('invalid', function () {
    this.setCustomValidity('This is an invalid number');
});

$('[type=number]').on('input', function () {
    console.log('setCustomValidity() reset');
    this.setCustomValidity('');
});

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    console.log('submitted');
});
```